# use password/code to get to login/register page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I've been working on and implementing Satellizer (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) on my application.

What I'm looking at doing is when someone click on "Login" it will take them to an access page where the user has to enter the correct access password (only password, no username) to get through to the login page. Why you might ask? Well I want to only let people with the access code/password to have access to the login and register pages. Basically 2 different authentication processes to get into the application.

This is where I'm stuck. Can I use the same json web token for both login/register and the access page? or do I need to create a new standalone authentication for this access page?

If I need to provide more information please let me know, thx.

Answer (score 0):

so what you are trying to accomplish here with this authentication system is to make sure that who ever is accessing the system must be authenticated first then it will be redirected to login page ?

If that the case I think you will NOT be able to do this with this particular authentication system because it always require username OR email address... don't you think ?? you will have to use another username password authentication system but instead of checking username and password both you will have to check only password OR access code.

Comment: This is what I had in mind yes. Have been trying different types of authentication (prefer tokens since I can set expiry time), but no luck thus far. Any tips?

Comment: don't know about token system, I've worked with user/password authentication system, did you search it on github ?

Comment: I did, but didn't find anyone that suited my needs.

Comment: and what back-end are you using with it ?

Comment: So you need

1: token based system which would expire its token after some time
2: you don't want username to be shown
3: just authenticate using access code or password
 
an idea just came to my mind, why don't you use the current system but instead of authenticating both username and password you just have to authenticate password or instead of password make another table in your DB with access code and when the request is send from access authentication page match the access code with that.

Comment: Will have a look at it. I'm using the MEAN-stack, node.js as back-end. I tried authenticating with only access code, encrypting the access code and decrpyting after with bcrypt. But the issue I came to was that it encrypted it again and checked vs the first one when I did bcrypt.compare. Scrapped that idea though. I'm currently looking at passwordless authentication, but progress is slow.

Comment: OK, I'm checking but lets see if you need any other help do let me know. Thanks